# How do I count the amount of 'edges' in a word in Python, using a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

For this exercise I need to count the 'number of edges' in the word 'AARDGASRESERVES' (Dutch), using a for loop and a dictionary. I already have the following code, but this doesn't give me the required output (which should be 31). I believe the middle part isn't quite right yet.

```
# dictionary of number of edges per letter
edges = {"A": 2, "R": 2, "D": 0,"G": 2,"S": 2,"R": 2,"E": 3, "V": 2}

word = "AARDGASRESERVES"

# loop over the letters in the word and count the number of edges
total_edges = 0
for key in edges:
    if edges[key] == word:
        total_edges += [value]

# print the total
print("Total number of edges:", total_edges)
```

I tried `if edges[key] in word:` too but that results in an error. I'm still new to Python so I might have written something that isn't even possible.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do what you want is:

```
edges = {"A": 2, "R": 2, "D": 0,"G": 2,"S": 2,"R": 2,"E": 3, "V": 2}
word = "AARDGASRESERVES"

total_edges = sum([edges[c] for c in word])

# print the total
print("Total number of edges:", total_edges) # Output: 31
```

---

However, I advise you to *carefully* examine your code to understand why it doesn't work. For example here:

```
...
if edges[key] == word:
...
```

you compare if a **number** (value of your dict) is equal to the whole **word**, which is an irrational `if-statement`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment. Now I see that that if-statement is not a good one. As I said, I'm new to Python, so comments like this are really appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome! Since you're so new, try when you have a problem like this to use `print` statements to see what the values of your variables are. Is a very first way of "debugging" to understand what is going wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about the purpose of this code. It should go about this

```
    # dictionary of number of edges per letter
    edges = {"A": 2, "R": 2, "D": 0,"G": 2,"S": 2,"R": 2,"E": 3, "V": 2}

    word = "AARDGASRESERVES"

    # loop over the letters in the word and count the number of edges
    total_edges = 0
    for key in word:
        total_edges += edges[key]

    # print the total
    print("Total number of edges:", total_edges)
```

What you want to do is to get a letter from the word and get the specific element associated with that key and add it.

Comment: Thank you! That is indeed what I was looking for. Thanks for the explanation too, it really does help me a lot learning Python